# Mysql with Python can't insert record with autoincrement id, why?

Tags: python, mysql, insert, record, auto-increment

I create a table 'test' with two column:(age int, name TEXT) in mysql database.

Then I insert a record using the following codes(with a list):

```
record = [12, 'Tom']
cursor.execute("insert into test values(%s,%s)", record)
```

The above codes work in mysql(I use python 2.7 for programming).

I then delete the old table and want to add an AUTO_INCREMENT P_id field for the new table, by adding the following code to the CREATE TABLE sql:

```
P_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

And the new table works and I find it in mysql.
However, when I try to insert a new record using the same codes:

```
record = [12, 'Tom']
cursor.execute("insert into test values(%s,%s)", record)
```

But it doesn't work and reports:

```
OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

It looks like I should add the value of P_id by myself?
But should it increase automatically and I can omit that?
I'm quite a newbie in mysql and please help with details.

This is my first time question in StackOverflow and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this query:

```
insert into test (age,name) values(%s,%s)
```

Your code will look like:

```
record = [12, 'Tom']
cursor.execute("insert into test (age,name) values(%s,%s)", record)
```

Comment: Your answer is so timely and great.

Comment: It works quite well. Thanks so much. I now realize that the default setting is supposed to update all the field. So great the first experience in Stackoverflow. :)